# how to get edit access to /var/www/html on apache2 server on Ubuntu

Tags: php, html, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I have tried to get edit access to the /var/www/html folder on my apache2 server to edit html and php files. It is possible to edit trough the terminal with sudo command, but I want a graphical editor that is easier to use. I have downloaded BlueFish but it is not possible to navigate to the /var/www/html folder because it is read only.

Comment: Give us more information, type in terminal `ls -l /var/www/html`

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/a/30635/269282

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you don't have right permission and you don't own this directory.

```
sudo chown -R group:user /var/www/html
sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www/html
```

Instead of `group:user` put your group and user name, default `username:username`, for instance

```
 sudo chown -R safirfox:safirfox /var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

Start `gedit` using `sudo` at the command line and then edit graphically:

```
sudo gedit /var/www/html/index.html

sudo gedit
```

Comment: He already said that "It is possible to edit trough the terminal with sudo command", so he knows about it but it isn't solution, only workaround.

Comment: No. He said he can edit in the terminal, which sounds like `vi` or `emacs`. My suggestion is a perfectly reasonable one for graphical editing which is what he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

to do that you can change the folder permissions, the way

```
sudo chown $USER -R /var/www/html/
```